# Setting up a wired and wireless router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, debian, wireless-router

I have a little box I use as a print server now. It has a wireless card and two ethernet ports, and I'd like to use it to replace my router, as it supports ac and my current router only supports G. I have a gaming PC that sits by the router but has no wireless card. I've found lots of guides online as to how to set up a box as a wireless router OR wired router, if I want to set up this box as both, how would I get started? Ideally the machines on the wired and wireless networks would be able to see each other.

Also, the little box is running Debian and is a FitPC4: http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/fit-pc4/
Thanks.

Debian is Jessie. Relevant sections of lspci are:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 08b1 (rev 73)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

The wireless is WLAN 802.11ac (2.4/5GHz dual band Intel 7260HMW)

Comment: Please, tell us which version of Debian are you running on FitPC4 and which wireless card it includes. The output of "lspci" might help, should you have problems identifying the wireless card

Comment: These have been added.